# How to create a duplicate of a folder such that they update together?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, files-folders

**Why there is an issue?:**
I have a habit of organising my folder/files in the file explorer of Windows 10. I don't have the best-organised structure, and thus there is a need that if I update (by adding a file in it) a folder `My Pics` at some path say `Downloads\My Pics` and the copy of the same folder which is at `Documents\My Pics` should also get updated real-time.
**What is the issue?:**
Is there some way to *link* two/multiple folders in file explorer so that they are a real-time copy of each other all the time?
If not. Then are there some alternative software/tweaks that will help me in this issue?
**PS:** *This is my first question on superuser so I might not have framed my question properly but feel free to ask me if my problem is not apparent.*

Comment: I think you are looking for foldrre/shortcuts. Google them!

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the reply, but in my case, a shortcut won't do the job as I need the two folders to have different paths.  The problem I expressed above is a much-simplified version of my actual requirement.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some context as to why a shortcut won't do? In my eyes this would have looked like a perfect solution.

Comment: Sorry, when I said folder, I meant symlink.  Not sure how well symlinks work in a Windows environment though .

Comment: @creyD My bad. I shared a folder with my friends in my class on google drive (some lectures). The path I chose for this was manually uploading the folder to google drive then get a share link for them. But soon I realised the hassle of manually updating each new lectures into the folder from my local copy. I came across Google Backup & Sync only to realise that I should have used it to first automatically to sync my local folder and then get the share link. Now I wanted to link the existing shared folder to my local copy. (All this just not to change the share link {:sweat_smile:} )

Comment: @davidgo thanks for the correction **harrymc** has provided a solution for the same. I am yet to check it. I hope this solves my problem as the article cited by him says "This trick can be used for all sorts of things, including syncing any folder with programs like Dropbox, **Google Drive**, and OneDrive.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for
[symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link):
"a term for any file that contains a reference to another file or directory in the form of an absolute or relative path and that affects pathname resolution."

See the article
[The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)
for a complete treaty of the subject.

Comment: Thank You so much @harrymc!!...... This is exactly what I needed.